# Renaming files with a specific scheme

Tags: bash

I have a FTP folder receiving files from a remote camera. The camera stores the video file name always as `./rec_YYYY-MM-DD_HH-MM.mkv`. The video files are stored all in the same folder, the root folder from the FTP server.

I need to move these files to another folder, with this new scheme:

- Remove `rec_` from the file name.
- Change date format to `DD-MM-YY`.
- Remove date from the file name and make it a folder instead, where that same file and all the others in the same date will be stored in.
- Final file path would be: `./DD-MM-YYYY/HH-MM.mkv`.
- The process would continue to all the files, putting them in the folder corresponding to the day it was created.

Summing up: `./rec_YYYY-MM-DD_HH-MM.mkv` >> `./DD-MM-YYYY/HH-MM.mkv`. The same should apply to all files that are in the same folder.

As I can't make it happen directly from the camera, this needs to be done with Bash on the server that is receiving the files.

So far, what I got is script, which would get the file's creation date and use it to make a folder, and then get creation time to move the file with the new name, based on it's creation time.:

```
for f in *.mp4
do
    mkdir "$f" "$(date -r "$f" +"%d-%m-%Y")"
    mv -n "$f" "$(date -r "$f" +"%d-%m-%Y/%H-%M-%S").mp4"
done
```

I'm getting this output (with testfile `1.mp4`):

- It creates the folder based on the file's creation date;
- it renames the file to it's creation time;
- Then, it returns `mkdir: cannot create directory ‘1.mp4’: File exists`
- If two or more files, only one gets renamed and moved as described. The others stay the same and terminal returns:

`mkdir: cannot create directory ‘1.mp4’: File exists
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘2.mp4’: File exists
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘12-12-2018’: File exists`

Could someone help me out? Better suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Use the `-p` argument to `mkdir` to ignore directories that already exist. And use `bash -x yourscript` to run it with trace-level logging -- that tracing should help you identify a narrow, specific problem appropriate to our format.

Comment: DON'T swap YY with DD! the original format `YYYY-MM-DD_HH-MM` lets you have a sorted directory listing, with `ls` from older to newer, with `ls -r` from newer to older day of recording.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly I would just use Perl or Python for this. Here's how to embed either in a shell script.

Here's a perl script that doesn't use any libraries, even ones that ship with Perl (so it'll work without extra packages on distributions like CentOS that don't ship with the entire Perl library). The perl script launches one new process per file in order to perform the copy.

```
perl -e '

while (<"*.m{p4,kv}">) {
    my $path = $_;
    my ($prefix, $year, $month, $day, $hour, $minute, $ext) = 
        split /[.-_]/, $path;
    my $sec = q[00];
    die "unexpected prefix ($prefix) in $path"
        unless $prefix eq q[rec];
    die "unexpected extension ($ext) in $path"
        unless $ext eq q[mp4] or $ext eq q[mkv];
    my $dir = "$day-$month-$year";
    my $name = "$hour-$min-$sec" . q[.] . $ext;
    my $destpath = $dir . q[/] . $name;
    die "$dir . $name is unexpectedly a directory" if (-d $dir);
    system("cp", "--", $path, $destpath);
}
'
```

Here's a Python example, it's compatible with either Python 2 or Python 3 but does use the standard library. The Python script does not spawn any additional processes.

```
python3 -c '
import os.path as path
import re
from glob import iglob
from itertools import chain
from os import mkdir
from shutil import copyfile

for p in chain(iglob("*.mp4"), iglob("*.mkv")):
  fields = re.split("[-]|[._]", p)
  prefix = fields[0]
  year   = fields[1]
  month  = fields[2]
  day    = fields[3]
  hour   = fields[4]
  minute = fields[5]
  ext    = fields[6]
  sec    = "00"
  assert prefix == "rec"
  assert ext in ["mp4", "mkv"]
  directory = "".join([day, "-", month, "-", year])
  name = "".join([hour, "-", minute, "-", sec, ".", ext])
  destpath = "".join([directory, "/", name])
  assert not path.isdir(destpath)
  try:
    mkdir(directory)
  except FileExistsError:
    pass
  copyfile(src=p, dst=destpath)
'
```

Finally, here's a bash solution. It splits paths using `-`, `.`, and `_` and then extracts various subfields by indexing into `$@` inside a function. The indexing trick is portable, although regex substitution on variables is a bash extension.

```
#!/bin/bash


#   $1  $2  $3 $4 $5 $6 $7  $8
# path  rec YY MM DD HH MM ext
process_file() {
  mkdir "$5-$4-$3" &> /dev/null
  cp -- "$1" "$5-$4-$3"/"$6-$7-00.$8"
}

for path in *.m{p4,kv}; do
    [ -e "$path" ] || continue
    # NOTE: two slashes are needed in the substitution to replace everything
    # read -a ARRAYVAR <<< ... reads the words of a string into an array
    IFS=' ' read -a f <<< "${path//[-_.]/ }"
    process_file "$path" "${f[@]}"
done
```

Comment: Hm. Personally, I'd probably use a regex (results stored in the `BASH_REMATCH` array) rather than the string-splitting hackery. If one has set `re='^rec_([[:digit:]]+)-([[:digit:]]+)-([[:digit:]]+)_([[:digit:]]+)-([[:digit:]]+)[.]mkv$'`, then `if [[ $path =~ $re ]]; then process_file "$path" "${BASH_REMATCH[@]:1}"; fi` will skip the `rec`, and just pass YY MM DD HH MM (the capture groups) through to `process_file`.

Comment: That way you don't try to process files that aren't in the named format -- otherwise, if you had, say, a file created with `touch '* .mkv'`, you don't have the unquoted expansion replacing the `*` with a list of files in the local directory.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy are you going to write an answer? If not, may I incorporate your improvements into my answer?

Comment: I'm not; feel free.

Comment: The python script gives me this:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
AssertionError`

The bash script worked perfectly.

Comment: @AndréLuís the python and perl scripts have more error checking. You'd get a failure on line 20 if the 7th part of any of the files processed wasn't the extension `mkv` or `mp4`. Do you have files in your directory with the `mp4` or `mkv` extension that don't fit the naming convention?

Answer (score 1):

If you `cd /to/some/directory/containing_your_files` then you could use the following script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for f in rec_????-??-??_??-??.m{p4,kv} ; do
    dir=${f:4:10} # skip 4 chars ('rec_') take 10 chars ('YYYY_MM_DD')
    fnm=${f:15}   # skip 15 chars, take the remainder
    test -d "$dir" || mkdir "$dir"
    mv "$f" "$dir"/"$fnm"
done
```

note ① that I have not exchanged the years and the days, if you absolutely need to do the swap you can extract the year like this, `year=${dir::4}` etc and ② that this method of parameter substitution is a Bash-ism, e.g., it doesn't work in `dash`.

Comment: Will check that.

Answer (score -1):

your problem is:  mkdir creates folder but you are giving filename for folder creation.

if you want to use fileName for folder creation then use it without extension.

the thing is you are trying to create folder with the already existing fileName

[image]

Comment: That they're passing `"$f"` to `mkdir` (thus trying to create a directory with the name of the already-existing output file) is indeed a bug, but it's only responsible for spurious error messages, as opposed to changing actual behavior; the final argument to `mkdir` is still a proper, extension-free directory name.

Comment: but there is already a file with the same name. that is why it is giving File exists error.

Comment: Yes, there *is* already a file with the same name (since the input file is being passed as an argument to `mkdir` for no good reason), and that *is* why `mkdir` gives the error, but that error is irrelevant to whether the `mv`s succeed or fail.

Comment: mv fails because there is no folder on the target side since the prior command mkdir failed

Comment: Wrong! `mkdir` is passed two separate arguments, and it only fails for the first one. The second directory is properly created. You can test this yourself: `mkdir foo; mkdir foo bar` throws an error, but it *does* create `bar`, even though `foo` already existed.

Comment: ...so the `mkdir test.sh` in your screenshot isn't what the OP's code is actually doing.

Comment: My slow brain is still processing all these informations. ehhehe

Comment: Maybe I could use `find` to target the oldest file and do it one by one, as each file arrive every 5 mins. But I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: I don't think there's much reason to worry about order, so long as there are never two files created in the same minute -- just switch to `mkdir -p` so it's not an error if an argument already exists (as a directory). And of course the OP needs to take `"$f"` off their `mkdir`'s argument list.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy you were right. `mkdir -p` and removing `"$f"` from `mkdir`'s argument list did the thing with 2 files without any errors. https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPnML.png

Comment: @CharlesDuffy could you guys check my answer? I'm stuck there. Thanks!